# Disable Back button and Recent Task App Button when Intent called in android

Tags: android

I am developing an app that launches app from the device. I was thinking if it is possible to **disable the Back and Recent Task App Buttons** of the other application that will be called once a button is clicked?

**EDIT:**

I am developing an app in kiosk mode and I have a button (let's call it `btn_CallApp`) there **to start another application** from the device. In my kiosk app, the buttons are perfectly disabled except for Home Button. When I click the btn_CallApp, it will call the startActivity() which will go to the application that I provided.

```
public void onButtonClicked(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {     
    case R.id.btn_CallApp:
        Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.registrationform");
        LaunchIntent.putExtra("isFullScreen", true);
        startActivity(LaunchIntent);
         break;
    }
}
```

It actually runs the Registration form Project but the Back Button and Recent Task App Button are enabled again.

Now, my question is, how can I disable those Button when I call the other application?

Comment: It's not possible for other apps that you don't have control to.

Comment: but is it possible to disable the buttons when I launch another app from my launching application?

Comment: Maybe, it's possible if the app permits to do so (through `Intent` or flag or something). However, I don't think most of the apps implement this function, unless the app is specifically purposed created for kiosk mode.

Comment: Yeah, I'm doing kiosk mode that launches app that's why I need to disable the button when the uploaded app is running

Comment: I am not doing my app well. :( do you have a sample source code for kiosk mode that can add/remove apps?

Comment: Sorry to say, but I don't have any experience in kiosk mode at all. This is as much as I can explain.

Answer (score 0):

for other apps it is not possible.

Comment: Aw! However is it possible to disable the buttons when I launch another app from my launching application?

Comment: which one button you want to disable.

Comment: Back and Recent Task App Button

Comment: in your app you can disable back button.but i think you can't disable recent tasks button(work after long press home button).

Comment: In my kiosk app, I can disable both buttons but when I start to launch applications from there, the buttons became enable again since it is not coded to disable the buttons.

Comment: please explain the problem...and what have you done and wt you want.